# codesleeve asset pipeline, can't load images from CSS in production

Tags: php, css, laravel, asset-pipeline

I am using Laravel 4 PHP framework, and for that I have found this nice [Codesleeve asset pipeline](https://github.com/CodeSleeve/asset-pipeline) vendor, which provides me with a pipeline for my assets (JS, CSS and images).

What I am trying to, is to load a background image (which is stored in the images directory), from my css file. It works when I am developing on local machine, then I can access my image from inside the CSS file, just by writing the image file name as the url.

```
background: url('black-bg.jpg') repeat top left;
```

however my CSS file can't load the image file when it's on production. Though I can access the image from the same url as on local machine assets/black-bg.jpg

So please help me with my problem. My website works fine on localhost, but on production server, it won't get the background image from my CSS file.

What can be wrong?

Comment: this CSS code will only work if CSS file and the image are in the same directory, otherwise will need a fullpath e.g. `http://example.com/images/black-bg.jpg` or correct use parent levels `../`

Comment: but why does the asset pipeline, then provide me with an images folder?

Comment: I think I have found the error... The CSS was breaking, beacause of some error when minifying Twitter Bootstrap... I have solved it by using the bootstrap.min.css file, instead of the not minified one, since codesleeve asset-pipeline will not minify files, with the file ending .min.css - I can now have my images in the images folder as supposed to.